# Can Mathematica perform logical reasoning?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, code-request, logic

The question goes like this:

Ms. Li has just moved into a new home and plans to buy several potted plants at once. Her thoughts are as follows:

1. Buy either Green Radish or Podocarpus.
2. Buy at least one of Spider Plant, Green Radish, and Rubber Tree.
3. Buy at least two of Podocarpus, Rubber Tree, and Sansevieria.
4. If Podocarpus is bought, then Spider Plant is not bought.

If all the above conditions are met,

then Which of the following options A, B, C, D is necessarily correct?:

A. Ms. Li bought Sansevieria.

B. Ms. Li bought Rubber Tree.

C. Ms. Li bought either Podocarpus or Spider Plant.

D. Ms. Li bought at least three kinds of potted plants.

---

The reasoning goes like this:

The question asks which option is necessarily correct, and one approach is to start from a modus tollens reasoning.

The only if-then statement in the question is sentence 4: If Podocarpus is bought, then Spider Plant is not bought.

From sentence 1, we can derive that if Podocarpus is bought, then Green Radish is not bought either.

Combining these two conditions, we can conclude that if Podocarpus is bought, then both Spider Plant and Green Radish are not bought, which leads to the necessity of buying Rubber Tree.

From sentence 3, if Podocarpus is not bought, then Rubber Tree and Sansevieria must be bought.

Therefore, whether Podocarpus is bought or not, Rubber Tree must be bought. The answer is B.

Comment: Do you know the answer? Or how you would solve it by hand ? Or are you just looking for natural language driven AI solutions?

Comment: There is ambiguity in the constraint  statements. Further, is it a statement that "all the following statements are true" or is meant to be a question of which is true (as allued to by @Syed)? Mathematica can deal with logical statements using `Reduce` and simplify using `BooleanMinimize` once statements have been coded. If it is a  question about natural language processing: I defer to others.

Comment: `BooleanMinimize[{G ⊻ P && S ∨ G ∨ 
    R && (P ∧ R ) ∨ (P ∧ S) ∨ (R ∧ S) && 
     P \[Implies] ¬ S}]` gives `{(! G && ! P) || ! S}`

Comment: @Syed  The question has been clarified.

Comment: @Syed I think your approach is what is desired. Your interpretation regards first statement as exclusive or (how do you know that), and you appear to use S for 2 different plants.

Comment: Using `S` twice is an oversight. Please change it to `V` for `Sansevieria` and rerun. Since `R` is not part of the final output, it means that statement `(B)` can be `True` or `False` without further clarification. Either/or in English translates to `XOR` or so I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just a slight variation on the excellent answer given by Bill, which is too long for a comment.

***Boolean Variables***

The truth values of `gr`, `sp`, `rt`, `s`, `pod` indicate whether *Green Radish*, *Spider Plant*, *Rubber Tree*, *Sansevieria*, or *Podcarpus* are bought or not.

***Entering Conditions***

```
c1 = gr \[Xor] pod;
c2 = sp \[Or] gr \[Or] rt;
c3 = ( { pod, rt, s } // Query[ Total, Boole ] ) >= 2;
c4 = pod \[Implies] \[Not] sp;
conditions = And @@ { c1, c2, c3, c4 };
```

*Note that you can enter the logical operators using `Esc` `str` `Esc` with `str` being `xor`, `or`, `=>`, or `not`.*

***Entering Options***

```
options = Association[
    "A" -> s,
    "B" -> rt,
    "C" -> pod \[Xor] sp,
    "D" -> ( { gr, rt, pod, sp, s } // Query[ Total, Boole ]) > 2
];
```

*Note that since we decided to understand "either ... or" as an exclusive or in encoding the conditions, we should be consistent in encoding option C.*

***Checking Necessity***

A predicate P is necessary for the conditions C, if $C \implies P$ is $true$. Thus

```
options // Query[All /* Dataset, conditions \[Implies] #& /* FullSimplify /* SameAs[True] ]
```

[image: Solution]

***Remarks***

1. I find `Query[Total, Boole]` applied to a list of variables and then checking this sum against an integer easier than working with subsets and lots of alternatives.
2. Unfortunately, `BooleanMinimize` seems to "choke" on sums of Booles (1.), but fortunately `FullSimplify` does not. Maybe someone can further comment on this observation?

Comment: +1. Thank you for the wonderful education on use of ‘Query’ for this. :)

Comment: @ubpdqn You are welcome. I must, in return, thank [Seth Chandler](https://www.wolfram.com/language/query-getting-information-from-data-with-the-wolfram-language/) for having instigated my more frequent use of it.

Answer (score 17):

This may be close.

```
cond1 = (gr && ! Pod) || (Pod && ! gr)

cond2 = sp || gr || rt || (sp && gr) || (sp && rt) || (gr && rt) || (sp && gr && rt)

cond3 = (Pod && rt) || (Pod && San) || (San && rt) || (Pod && rt && San)

cond4 = Pod \[Implies] \[Not] sp

cond = cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4

BooleanMinimize[cond]

(gr && ! Pod && rt && San) || (! gr && Pod && rt && ! sp)
```

So she bought either

Green Radish and Rubber Tree and Sansevieria
or

Podocarpus and Rubber Tree.

And the only necessary answer is B since the rubber tree is the only plant in both purchase options.

Comment: For the last step, you can use `BooleanMinimize` too e.g. `Implies[(gr && ! Pod && rt && San) || (! gr && Pod && rt && ! sp), #] & /@ {San, rt, Pod || sp, Or @@ And @@@ Subsets[{gr, Pod, rt, San}, {3, 4}]} // BooleanMinimize`

Comment: @xzczd Good to know. There are probably better ways to code some of the conditions than I have here also.  I am a little rusty on my boolean logic.